# Ng-repeat - "Are you sure to delete ?" from a modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, slice

I'm retrieving a list of objects (item) from a Django API.

```
  my_app.factory('list_of_items', function($resource) {
        return $resource(
            '/api/petdata/') });
```

Then I display everything in a html page within a `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{display:'1'} | orderBy: 'item_name'">
     <div class="box box-widget widget-user">
    {{ item.pet_name }}{% endverbatim %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-click="askDelete(item)" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </div>
<div>
```

Everything's fine so far. 
Then I want the user to be able to delete one of the item by clicking on the button from the html page. 
What means deleting here : 
1. Update the API database by changing the property "display:1" to "display:0". 
2. Remove the item from the ng-repeat.

I want to make a "Are you sure" modal to confirm the delete process.
This is the `askDelete` function.

```
angular.module('djangular-demo').controller('Ctrl_List_Of_Pets', function($scope, $http, $window,$filter,list_of_pets,pet_by_id,$uibModal) {

$scope.items = list_of_items.query()

  $scope.askDelete = function (idx,item,size,parentSelector) {
    // console.log("PET",$scope.pet_to_be_undisplayed);
    var parentElem = parentSelector ? 
      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: true,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'LOL',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: "myModalContent.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.ok = function() {
    modalInstance.close();
  };


  $scope.cancel = function() {
    modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

      },
      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem,
      resolve: {
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function() {
      reallyDelete(item);
    });

  };

    var reallyDelete = function(item) {

      $scope.entry = items_by_id.get({ id: item.id }, function() {
      // $scope.entry is fetched from server and is an instance of Entry
      $scope.entry.display = 0;
      $scope.entry.$update({id: $scope.entry.id},function() {
        //updated in the backend
      });
    });  

    $scope.items = window._.remove($scope.items, function(elem) {
      return elem != item;
    });
  };

});
```

What works :
Updating the DB works with a PUT request (code hasn't been provided).

What doesn't work : 
Removing the item from the ng-repeat never works. Or it throws me an error like here because it doesn't know  `window._.remove` or it doesn't know `$scope.items`. It depends from what I try. Or the modal close and there is no update of the ng-repeat list, no refresh and every items remain whereas the PUT request to update worked.

I read every article on scope inheritance and I think I didn't make any mistake here but I'm might be wrong. I've been struggling for too long so I post here !

Would you suggest anything to make it work ?

Thank you for your rime.

Comment: Why not just make another GET request after your PUT request finishes to update the list with what's actually in the database instead of manually removing the entry from the front-end?

Comment: i agree with @BenBeck that way you know you have the correct info. If you don't want to make a GET request then you can just keep the index of the item and do `$scope.items.splice(1, $index)`

Comment: The approach mentioned by @BenBeck is completely valid (and a good one), but, also, if we are sure the service updated the DB properly, it could be nice just update the client side with angular (splice the element) and avoid this way another call the  backend service (just saying, this is another valid option too) :)

Comment: Agreeing with both Ero and @lealceldeiro here. The dependent factor is really based upon the performance of your GET request. i.e. if you have to GET 5000 items you may want to consider doing only the splice. If you only have to GET maybe 100 items then I would consider making the subsequent GET request.

Comment: Thank you for all of your detailed and relevant comments !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

`$scope.askDelete = function (idx,item,size,parentSelector)` receives the item index, the item, size, and parent selector... and you are calling `ng-click="askDelete(item)"`

I assume you are attempting to pass the item, but in `askDelete` you are receiving as first parameter the index (maybe you should do `ng-click="askDelete($index)"`?)

**Second:**

In `reallyDelete` why are you removing the items array like this:

```
$scope.items = window._.remove($scope.items, function(elem) {
  return elem != item;
});
```

?

IMHO, it would be a much cleaner code if we just do:

```
$scope.items.splice(idx, 1) //<- idx would be the idx of the entry in the items
```

*You may want to take a look at [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)*